# Office 365 REST API - Creating a Contact gives me HTTPCode 400

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest, office365

I am using the Office 365 Rest API and I am having problems in creating a Contact:

I am doing this:

```
public async Task<bool> CreateContact(Contact contact)
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Contacts"));

        // Add the Authorization header with the basic login credentials.
        var auth = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_user + ":" + _password));
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", auth);
        var createResponse = new JObject();
        createResponse["@odata.type"] = "#Microsoft.Exchange.Services.OData.Model.Contact";
        createResponse["DisplayName"] = contact.Name;
        createResponse["EmailAddress1"] = contact.Email;
        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createResponse), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json;odata.metadata=full");

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

that give me

`` {System.FormatException: The format of value 'application/json;odata.metadata=full' is invalid.
    at System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue.CheckMediaTypeFormat(String mediaType, String parameterName)
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue..ctor(String mediaType)
   at System.Net.Http.StringContent..ctor(String content, Encoding encoding, String mediaType)
   at SharePointPTSample.Office365.Office365Service.d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at SharePointPTSample.ViewModels.EditContactViewModel.d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.b__3(Object state)} ``

but if I change the value "application/json;odata.metadata=full" to "application/json", 
It gives me 400

`{StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 0.0, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: private
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
  request-id: 3679d732-ae03-4358-b256-3738cbf24030
  X-CalculatedBETarget: dbxpr06mb352.eurprd06.prod.outlook.com
  X-DiagInfo: DBXPR06MB352
  X-BEServer: DBXPR06MB352
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=daa5b4f2b05b422f8c5e99105e617429; expires=Sun, 05-Jul-2015 22:06:47 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly,  X-BackEndCookie=< removed it for post>; expires=Mon, 04-Aug-2014 22:06:47 GMT; path=/ews; secure; HttpOnly
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  X-FEServer: AMXPR05CA0040
  Date: Sat, 05 Jul 2014 22:06:47 GMT
  Content-Length: 567
  Content-Type: application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true; IEEE754Compatible=false; charset=utf-8
}}`

I follow this link

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605896(v=office.15).aspx#bkContact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605896%28v=office.15%29.aspx#bkContact)

What is missing? I did not undertand :/

I have Delete, Update and GetContacts working.

The complete source code is here:
https://github.com/saramgsilva/Office365RESTAPISample

Comment: Sara since you are getting a Bad Request I was wondering if auth has a special character in it from data being converted to a base64 string

Comment: `but if I do` Why don't you simply say what you have changed, and make us to read all the code line by line.

Comment: In1st sample i use:"application/json;odata.metadata=full" and in the second i use "application/json" ...@Ken the base64 is ok, i got it in fiddler too...i have it working for delete, update and getcontacts....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

saramgsilva,
Thanks for trying the API. 
I tried your code and a couple of things.
1. You need to specify ContentType Header as application/json. Leave the odata part out.
2. After you give that, you would have seen the next issue, which is that Given name is required. Once you provide these two, you should get a 201.

```
        createResponse["GivenName"] = "Rohit1";
        request.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(createResponse));
        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
```

Comment: FINALYYYY!!!!!! :D  ahahah really nice, for now I have: Create, Delete, Update and GetContacts working! Really nice for that I want in my demo and REST API is more great for that i want rather than Office API Preview.... just updated my repository with it. Soon as I can will work in this sample... I think the documentation need more details about how to use it, more samples... :) Will publish it in MSDN Samples too, but now need to finish my presentation...

Comment: Glad it works Saramgsilva. Thanks for the feedback on the samples.